# Perform an action in the first retry attempt to save the message on the Database

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to save every message that comes to a RabbitMQ queue on a database, just for logging. After that, the message needs to be processed normally.

The problem is: this queue has a retry policy configured with `RetryOperationsInterceptor`, and every time there is some error when processing the message, the message is requeued and processed again. The logic to save the message is in the Listener that reads the queue, so instead of just one message save on the database, I have `3` (the number of retries that I configured).

See my `RetryOperationsInterceptor`:

```
@Bean
public RetryOperationsInterceptor defaultRetryOperationsInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
            .maxAttempts(3) 
            .backOffOptions(2000, 2.0, 10000)
            .build();
}
```

The container factory:

```
@Bean(name = FACTORY_CONTAINER_NAME)
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factoryQueueExample(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                        RetryOperationsInterceptor defaultRetryOperationsInterceptor) {

    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(getMessageConverter());
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);

    Advice[] adviceChain = {defaultRetryOperationsInterceptor};
    factory.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);

    return factory;
}
```

The queue Listener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MessageListener {

    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;
    private final MessageService messageService;

    @RabbitListener(queues = MessageConfiguration.QUEUE,
        containerFactory = MessageConfiguration.FACTORY_CONTAINER_NAME)
    public void process(SomeMessage someMessage) {

        messageRepository.save(someMessage); // transform to a entity and save on database
        messageService.process(someMessage); // process message
    }
}
```

I don't know if is a relevant information, but this queue has also a DLQ associated. After this retries, the message goes to a DLQ queue.

My ideia is find something in the Retry interceptor that could call a service on the first attempt, to save the message just once.

I'm open for another ideas to resolve this problem too, like save the attempt number with the message, just to show that is not a repetead message being save on the database, but the same message in a different attempt.

Comment: Show, please, how do you save into the DB? Where is that code?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, hi! The code is very simple, but I already edited the question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention how you apply a retry:

```
Advice[] adviceChain = {defaultRetryOperationsInterceptor};
factory.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
```

The same way you can write your own `MethodInterceptor` to write into DB. 
And when you define this custom advice in order *before* that `defaultRetryOperationsInterceptor`, the DB save will be called only once, just because such an operation is going to happen outside of retry and even before.

See more info about AOP in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop

Comment: You can also check the redelivered header: `public void process(SomeMessage someMessage, @Header(AmqpHeaders.REDELIVERED) boolean redelivered)`

Comment: @Artem, thank you for the information. I will try that. If I understood correctly I need to get a `Message`, call the `getBody` and convert the bytes to the `SomeMessage`. And I need to inject (somehow) the Repository in the class that implement Method Interceptor.

Comment: @GaryRussell, this is a easier solution, but the flag is always `false` to me.

Comment: Yeah... That sounds like a plan in case of AOP. However you really can consider Gary's advice. Not too bad to just check an extra `@Header` in your `@RabbitListener`!

Comment: Yes, I will try to found out why the flag is always false. I will return with a feedback when I solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... I think `AmqpHeaders.REDELIVERED` isn't involved here. The message doesn't return to queue it is spinned within a `retry interceptor`. I think we just don't have any hook to track such a hook from the target service code...

Comment: Well, there is a `RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext()` available from your service code, called within retry interceptor. This `RetryContext` has an API like `getRetryCount()`. I think this value should be enough for your to determine if you need to store to DB or not.

Comment: Sorry; yes, you need to use stateful retry for the REDELIVERED header to be set, so the message is actually redelivered by the broker, and that might affect ordering when you have a prefetch - sorry for the confusion. Another solution is to have the sender set the messageId property and use it to check if it's already in the database. If the sending system is Spring, the message converter has an option to set the messageId. Stateful retry needs a messageId too.

Comment: Hi! I was about to found out the reason too. The redelivered is only setted when the message returns to the Queue from Unacked to Ready, or something like that. When you use retry, the Spring framework not to this (I couldn't see that happenning), so the RabbitMQ not set the message with redelivered. If I interrupt the application in the middle of the retries, I force this behavior and when I get the message again from the Queue after the restart, the message came to me as redelivered.

Comment: Thank you Garry and Artem, I will process your messages :) and see what option I will choose.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to thanks to the [Artem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan) and [Garry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) helping me how to solve my problem.

Are there, at least, four solutions:

1. The `Advice` solution (see Garry's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296960/2387977))
2. The counter from `RetrySynchronizationManager`
3. The `messageId` solution
4. Use a statefull `RetryOperationsInterceptor`

The counter from `RetrySynchronizationManager` option can be easily used to my case:

```
int attempts = RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount();
boolean canSaveOnDatabase = attempts == 0;
```

The `messageId` option is necessary to the sender send a ID the identify uniquely that message. So, I could save and use that information on the database to know if the message is already persisted. This can be configured [by the MessagePostProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41021877/2387977) when calling some `send` method from `RabbitTemplate`.

The last option, with a statefull `RetryOperationsInterceptor` I could just look for the header `@Header(AmqpHeaders.REDELIVERED) boolean redelivered` in the `RabbitListener`. This option not works if you using a stateless `RetryOperationsInterceptor` (my case) and this option also needs a `messageId`.